# Mongoose aggregate always return documents although _id is not existed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using `$lt` operator in aggregate pipeline for my query to determine and get the documents if `_id` is less than to another value like `cursorId` but in my output I always get
results when I intentionally falsify `_id` value. In my case the user entered an object id from URL that **didn't existed** in the collection but myCollection always returned 10 documents newest. What is going on with my query code? What should I do to solve this problem? Is there a way to return an empty array if the `cursorId` doesn't exist in the collection?

Here is my aggregate pipelines code for my case:

```
  myCollection.aggregate([
     // sort documents by descending to get documents newest
     { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
     
     // get only documents where _id is less than cursorId
     {
        $match: {
           _id: { 
               $lt: ObjectId(cursorId) 
           }
        }
     },
      
     { $limit: 10 }
     
     // more stages...
  ]);
```

Comment: What is the value of `cursorId`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  cursorId is an ObjectId (e.g: `64a1c7214796bcddfd0eaf01`) which is doesn't exists in my collection

Comment: Maybe `myCollection.aggregate([...])toArray()`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  it not work for me :( What i need is to check the `cursorId` access by URL from the client inside the collection and make sure it is exist in any documents

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit hello, is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem, what is your problem?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  here is my mongo playground to describe my problem, please help me check it: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2OST_QSOVyC

Comment: `ObjectId("64a24a7f51e511bca00dc711").getTimestamp()` gives `2023-07-03T04:11:43.000Z`, all your document have an _id of `2023-07-03T04:03...` which is earlier (i.e. less) than your condition. So, what is your issue?